# HTML Label takes more new line space in iOS than Android

Tags: html, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

We are using **Xam.Plugin.HtmlLabel** plugin in our xamarin forms application. The HTML text we bind in this label has lots of paragraph tag and new lines tags. When we compare with Android device the space taken in it less when compared to iOS device.

**HTMLPage.xaml**

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
            <ScrollView
                Padding="24"
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
                <htmlLabel:HtmlLabel
                    x:Name="HTMLText"
                    LinkColor="{StaticResource LinkColor}"
                    TextColor="{StaticResource TextColor}" />
            </ScrollView>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

**HTMLPage.xaml.cs**

```
    using Xamarin.Forms;
    using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
    
    namespace Zhoosh.Views
    {
        [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
        public partial class HTMLPage : ContentPage
        {
            public HTMLPage(string Description)
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                HTMLText.Text = Description;
                
            }
        }
    }
```

**Sample HTML Text**

```html
"<p><b><span style='color: #396B94; font-family: Quicksand, sans-serif; font-size: 14pt;'>About C sharp language</span></b></p><p></p><p><span style='font-family: Quicksand, sans-serif; font-size: 14pt;'>The language is intended to be a simple, modern, general-purpose, object-oriented programming language. The language, and implementations thereof, should provide support for software engineering principles such as strong type checking, array bounds checking, detection of attempts to use uninitialized variables, and automatic garbage collection. Software robustness, durability, and programmer productivity are important.</span></p><p></p><p><span style='font-family: Quicksand, sans-serif; font-size: 14pt;'>The website provides information about the c sharp language.</span></p><p><br></p><p><br></p>";
```

Comment: by space you mean white blank space? or just the the amount of space this label has occupied? have you set the text size in your html?

Comment: Could you provide us the html string to test ? What's more, have you tried to use normal Label with `Html TextType`?

Comment: First, is it simply because the iOS device and Android device have different screen sizes and pixel density? What does the label look like on different iOS and Android devices, with larger/smaller screens, or higher pixel density? You can create a device in Android emulator that has screen size and pixel density close to that of the iOS device - then how does it look? OR iOS HTML may have different *defaults* than Android, for font sizes etc. To debug, start with very simple HTML text, no tags - does it "take same amount of space"? Then gradually add tags, one at a time.

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT I have attached the sample HTML. Could you check with it ??

Comment: Yes, I reproduced this issue , as ToolmakerSteve mentioned , it is happening because of the different screen size and the rendering way on Android and iOS .